# Buildbot not sending emails?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

I have a buildbot setup running for a software project, and am trying to set up e-mail notifications like so:

```
from buildbot.status import mail
c['status'].append(mail.MailNotifier(fromaddr=BUILDBOT_EMAIL,
                                     mode=('failing'),
                                     extraRecipients=[NOTIFICATION_EMAIL],
                                     sendToInterestedUsers=False))
```

Where `BUILDBOT_EMAIL` is a string "buildbot@name-of-our-project.org", and `NOTIFICATION_EMAIL` is a string with the email where I want to get the notifications.

According to [documentation](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#mailnotifier), everything seems fine; I am not sending mail to interested users so no `lookup` argument is required. I'm only trying to send mail to an explicitly stated address in case any build is failing. I am basically doing this:

> To get a simple one-message-per-build (say, for a mailing list), use
>   the following form instead. This form does not send mail to individual
>   developers (and thus does not need the lookup= argument, explained
>   below), instead it only ever sends mail to the extra recipients named
>   in the arguments:

```
mn = MailNotifier(fromaddr="buildbot@example.org",
                  sendToInterestedUsers=False,
                  extraRecipients=['listaddr@example.org'])
```

However, no e-mails are arriving even though I do have failing builds. What could be the cause?

Could there be a problem with the way I'm using fromaddr and simply using a `buildbot@domain-name.org` address as per examples? Should this address be registered in some way with our domain? Would it make a difference if I use `buildbot@localhost` instead?

Could the problem be caused by me not using `relayhost`? From the examples in the documentation it appears that this only needs to be set for authentication with the outbound -- not the inbound -- address.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check `twistd.log` for exceptions, errors, etc.

Comment: I resolved this issue 2 days ago now, and `twistd.log` was exactly the place where I started. I'll add a reply here soon so that I can share my solution and close the question. Thanks for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: @Boris: did you use PIP to install MTA for your buildbot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what kfunk suggested, I started by looking at twistd.log. It contained the following:

```
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [-] sending mail (868 bytes) to ['addr@example.com']
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTPSenderFactory instance at 0x31dc488>
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 5
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 4
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 3
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 2
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] SMTP Client retrying server. Retry: 1
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-02-09 04:26:18+0000 [Uninitialized] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

I tried to manually send an email from the machine's command line (using `sendmail`), but failed; it turned out that no SMTP server is up. The solution is to install and configure a mail transfer agent (for Ubuntu, the most common one seems to be Postfix so I installed that). There are many tutorials and manuals out there on how to install and configure Postfix so once I found that clue it was easy to go on.

There are many considerations on having your own SMTP server; for example finding a way to secure it against unauthorised access, otherwise it could be used by e.g. spammers. However, if you want to get e-mails from buildbot, you have to have an SMTP server so it's worth the effort to learn and configure it correctly.

Comment: May I know how did you install the MTA in buildbot? Did you install using PIP as buildbot uses virtual environment.

Comment: @nomanpouigt this was a long time ago so I'll look through my old notes later for more details but as far as I remember I just installed Postfix machine-wide with the normal Ubuntu package manager, see maybe something like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix